# How to put css code in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

i want to add a css code in a javascript function, this is the function that I have

```
function test1() {
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "test";
}
```

and i want this css code in it

```
p1 {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc,
               0 2px 0 #c9c9c9,
               0 3px 0 #bbb,
               0 4px 0 #b9b9b9,
               0 5px 0 #aaa,
               0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
               0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
               0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),
               0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
               0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
               0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
               0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
```

-

Basically, I have a paragraph (p1) and I use javascript because I made a button which onclick="test1()" so when it clicks it it will change the text to the one I put which is "test", but I don't want the whole paragraph to have the shadows, I only want the 'test' to have it, hope I was clear enough!

thank you

Comment: You do not need any special programming for CSS in your case. Just add it properly to your HTML.

Comment: Why do you want to use JavaScript for this?  If you just include your CSS file in the DOM, the styling will be applied.  If you want to switch styles dynamically, specify them in classes and just change the element's class property.

Comment: Maybe he want to dynamically add shadow?

Comment: hum well to make it in short, I have a paragraph (p1) and I use javascript because I made a button which onclick="test1()" so when it clicks it it will change the text to the one I put which is "test", but I don't want the whole paragraph to have the shadows, I only want the test to have it, hope I was clear enough!

Comment: Then use classes. `.shadow { ...... }` in CSS file, then `document.getElementById('p1').className = "shadow"`. A CSS class is much more meaningful than a bunch of style rules. I'd only add separate style rules where each element would be unpredictably different (like bar heights in a bar graph, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<p id="p1">
This is a <span>test.</span>
</p>
<button id="button1">Button</button>
```

From what I understand from your question, you want the function to add a shadow to JUST the word test. In that case using a `<span>` element might be the easiest way to achieve that. `.innerHTML()` does not select the text inside the `<p>` instead it *sets* the text  so you would have been left with an element with just the word 'test' inside.

And the javascript below can be modified to your liking, but the basic concept is there.

```
var button = document.getElementById("button1");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var p = document.getElementById("p1");
    var test = p.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
    test.style.textShadow = "5px 5px 1px #ff0000,10px 10px 1px #0000ff";
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lhc4tav/

Answer (score -1):

Something like that ?

```
document.getElementById("p1").style.textShadow = "5px 5px 1px #ff0000,10px 10px 1px #0000ff";
```

Found here : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_textshadow.asp

Comment: I know it's not very clean to do that and it is best to use some CSS classes  BUT this answer is correct. So, downvoting without commenting why, it's not constructive...

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to say, you should really post your HTML as well so we can better understand it. You can also try this if you can use jQuery:

```
$('.p1').css('text-shadow','0px 5px...etc');
```

But I agree that you may not need to do this via JS.